# Get the text from an external HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to get the text from a HTML document which does not call any functions from my `.jsp` file.

I've looked around and I thought I had found the answer to my problem but it doesn't seem to be working, and other answers consist of using jQuery (which I am both unfamiliar with and not allowed to use).

This is my code so far:

```
function getText(divID) {
    var w = window.open("test.html");
    var body = w.document.body;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
    var textContent = body.textContent || body.innerText;
    console.log(textContent);

    //div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textContent));
}
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to get the body of one HTML document and have it appear in another. Am I on the right tracks?

EDIT: Ok so I seem to have made my problem quite confusing. I call the function in a HTML document called `html.html`, but I want to get the text from `test.html`, then have it appear in `html.html`. It has to be like this because I can't assume that the HTML document I want to read from will include my `.jsp` file in its head.

At the moment I am getting the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Comment: The XMLHttpRequest object is better than opening a window.

Comment: Apart from what epascarello has said, elements don't have [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode) method, `document` has. You've to create the text node to the `document`, and then [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) it to the `div`.

Comment: This isn't currently my problem, as you can see it is commented out. The problem is the console produces: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined". test.html is in the same directory as the JSP, and I have another HTML file calling the function onload.

Comment: In that case you might want to edit your question, and tell us exactly what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `document.body` in the other `window` is `undefined`, is because the other `window` has not loaded and rendered the document yet.

One solution would be to wait for the `onload` event.

```
function getText(divID) {
    var w = window.open("test.html");
    w.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var body = w.document.body;
        var div = document.getElementById(divID);
        var textContent = body.textContent || body.innerText;
        console.log(textContent);
    });
}
```

Make sure you run the `getText` function on a user event like a click, else `window.open` will fail.

If all you want to do is get the contents of the other window, using AJAX would probably be a better option.

```
function getText(divID) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 ) {
            var body = xhr.response.body;
            var div = document.getElementById(divID);
            var textContent = body.textContent || body.innerText;
            console.log(textContent);
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "test.html", true);
    xhr.responseType = "document";
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Using this I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

As I said the test.html (The page to be read from) is in the same directory as both the jsp and html.html. Could it be a problem with my file structure?

Comment: @JamieBlue What browser are you using? `window.open` should not return `undefined`. Unless you are trying to run this outside a user event like a click?

Comment: I'm using google chrome, the problem was that it actually tried to open a new window, but blocked the pop-up. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry about this, is there a way to do this without the window actually opening in the browser each time I test it?

Comment: @JamieBlue Is there a reason you want to open the document in another window? You could just load the content via AJAX in the background.

Comment: No I don't need it visibly open in another window, I just need the text contents of test.html. I'm not familiar with AJAX, is it a language? If so, I'm required to use solely Javascript, HTML and CSS.

Comment: @JamieBlue AJAX is a way of requesting the contents of another file with JavaScript. I've added an example to my answer.